# How to Serial read two consecutive chars sent by computer to Arduino?

Tags: serial, sound, piezo

My program reads the input and plays the appropriate note for 500 milliseconds. If I type in 'a', tone(8, 440, 500) will be called. I now want to add different note lengths so that in the future, I can play songs by sending code to Arduino. I was thinking that if 'a' is typed in, the program checks the next character. If it's a 1, it's a whole note. If it's a 2, it's a half note. My code doesn't work. What is wrong with it?

```
    if(Serial.available()>0){
    char character=Serial.read();
    if(character=='a'){
    char leng=Serial.read();
    if(leng=='1'){
    tone(8, 440, 1000);
    delay(1000);
    }
    else if(leng=='2'){
    tone(8, 440, 500);
    delay(500);
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE! Could you please include the full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that code is the interior of `loop()`, your Arduino will spin until a character arrives, that is, until `Serial.available()>0` becomes true.

It then reads the character with `Serial.read()` and if it's an `'a'` immediately does another `Serial.read()`.  In general, some delay occurs between characters arriving via a serial interface.  Whenever the serial buffer is empty, an immediate `Serial.read()` will return -1 instead of an ASCII character.

To fix this problem, test for availability of a character before doing the second read.  For example, you could add

```
while (!Serial.available()){}
```

before the read, to delay until a character is available.